# Tests in AngularJS: Reference error of the inject function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, karma-runner

I try to test the code below:

```
describe('myService test', function () {
    describe('when I call myService.one', function () {
        beforeEach(angular.module('TargetMarketServices'));
        it('returns 1', inject(function (imagesRepository) {
            expect(true).toEqual(true);
        }));

    });

});
```

When this code is executed I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.func.apply(this.spec)')
    at http://localhost:8080/testacular.js:76
    at http://localhost:8080/context.html:35
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: inject
    at /home/peter/Dropbox/AngularJS/set-component/test/sets/sets-ihm.js:6
    at /home/peter/Dropbox/AngularJS/set-component/test/sets/sets-ihm.js:8
    at /home/peter/Dropbox/AngularJS/set-component/test/sets/sets-ihm.js:10
```

PhantomJS 1.8: Executed 1 of 3 (1 FAILED) (skipped 2) (0.072 secs / 0.01 secs)

For my test, I use Testacular with Jasmine and PhantomJS.

Answer (score 28):

AngularJS provides two testing libraries:

- angular-mocks.js
- angular-scenario.js

angular-mocks is used for Jasmine and Karma testing. It publishes global methods module() and inject() to be used in your Jasmine spec tests. This means you must load the angular-mocks.js script (after you load the angular.js library/script)

angular-scenario is only used for e2e testing.

Answer (score 13):

The line where you have

```
beforeEach(angular.module('TargetMarketServices'));
```

should be

```
beforeEach(module('TargetMarketServices'));
```

If you take a look at the [angular-phonecat](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat) project in test/unit/directivesSpec.js it uses

```
beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));
```

If I modify it to use angular.module instead:

```
beforeEach(angular.module('myApp.directives'));
```

then I get this error when running testacular also:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.func.apply(this.spec)')
```

Comment: But, when I use only module, I get the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module"

Comment: Sorry, I meant [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) earlier, not angular-phonecat.

You are getting that ReferenceError, I'm assuming, because you do not have [angular-mocks.js](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js) in your testacular unit testing configuration file.

Comment: The problem has been resolved by taking the angular-mocks.js file.

Comment: How about the answer get updated and accepted? I had the same issue, and this helped me resolve it.

Comment: You can also call `angular.mock.module('myApp');` instead of `module('myApp')` if `module` is overwritten (ie. browserify)